# identify json key by value and extract all matches

Tags: r, json

I have a json file and i have one of the values i want to extract. My Goal is to extract all values sharing the same key than the sample value).

**sample data:**

(from here: https://support.oneskyapp.com/hc/en-us/articles/208047697-JSON-sample-files)

```
{
    "quiz": {
        "sport": {
            "q1": {
                "question": "Which one is correct team name in NBA?",
                "options": [
                    "New York Bulls",
                    "Los Angeles Kings",
                    "Golden State Warriros",
                    "Huston Rocket"
                ],
                "answer": "Huston Rocket"
            }
        },
        "maths": {
            "q1": {
                "question": "5 + 7 = ?",
                "options": [
                    "10",
                    "11",
                    "12",
                    "13"
                ],
                "answer": "12"
            },
            "q2": {
                "question": "12 - 8 = ?",
                "options": [
                    "1",
                    "2",
                    "3",
                    "4"
                ],
                "answer": "4"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Let´s say i have the value "Which one is correct Team Name in NBA?" how do i programmatically find the corresponding key, to use it to extract the values sharing this same key.

**Desired Output:**

Find the keys:
Key1: "question"

Key2: "quiz, sport, q1, question"

And then finding the values sharing the same key:

`c("Which one is correct Team Name in NBA?", "5 + 7 = ?", "12 - 8 = ?")`

Comment: Your desired output is not clear.  May be `library(jsonlite);library(purrr);read_json(file) %>% modify_depth(3, ~ pluck(.x, 'question')) %>% unlist#                  quiz.sport.q1                            quiz.maths.q1                            quiz.maths.q2 
"Which one is correct team name in NBA?"                              "5 + 7 = ?"                             "12 - 8 = ?" `

Comment: thank you for your answer. I made an edit to the Question to be more precise on the desired Output. The Goal is to identify the key "Question", so it should not be part of the answer.

Comment: if you just need a unnamed vector then use `unlist(use.names = FALSE)`

Comment: that would give me all the values, not the desired subset that share the same key as the sample value,... (sry if that doesnt come out from the Question,...tried to be precise)